# XAP file is invalid

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

My phone is developer unlocked and I have installed windowsphone 8 SDK on my pc. When I try deploy any xap file from store and other source as well to my phone (device) it throws an error "XAP file is invalid"

Comment: Make sure the package is built using Release and not Debug.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the package is built using Release and not Debug.

You can refer the following links for more information-

http://slvideoplayer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=installation%20instructions&referringTitle=Home

and

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/deploying-wp7-xap-files-to-a-device-or-emulator